# how to declare/define hwmon sensor attributes in linux client driver at runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I am looking for a way to create hwmon sysfs nodes at runtime from the Linux kernel driver since a client driver will not maintain sensor list in the driver.

Our Linux kernel client driver does not know the sensor attributes/list at compile time. This driver will get the list of sensors available from **firmware** at runtime.
Based on the sensors, client driver has to create/register sysfs nodes with hwmon driver.

I am aware of declaring/adding sysfs node with hwmon device at compile time using below code snippet.

```c
/* In client driver */
static ssize_t show_sensor1_info(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *da, char *buf)
{
   // client driver displays sensor1 data
}

static struct sensor_device_attribute sensor_attr1 =
        SENSOR_ATTR(sensor1, 0444, show_sensor1_info, NULL, 0);

struct device *hdev = hwmon_device_register(&pdev->dev);

err = device_create_file(hdev, &sensor_attr1.dev_attr);
```

**Output**

```sh
$ ls /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/sensor1
sensor1
```

**Query:**
Client driver will not maintain sensor list at compile time. So, how to do the same job at runtime as client driver doesn't know list of sensors available.

It will know only after this driver is loaded. Once this driver's probe is called, it requests all available sensors list from hardware monitor firmware.

Comment: So, you have just prepare correct device tree, no? Why is it a topic of instantiating some drivers from another drivers?

Comment: Hi @0andriy client driver job is to get all sensors list from firmware and create hwmon sysfs node and register with hwmon driver. So, user can read the sensors using "lm-sensor" tool directly. This tool is already available on linux, user has to just install it and read the sensors using command "$sensors". Please let me know if something is not clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to create hwmon sysfs nodes based on the runtime sensor count.
I referred this code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3/source/drivers/hwmon/acpi_power_meter.c#L630 and it solved my requirement. Thanks.